# does read / write atomicity hold on multi-computer memory?

Tags: c, race-condition, pci

I'm working in a multi-computer environment where 2 computers will access the same memory over a 32bit PCI bus.

The first computer will only write to the 32bit int.
`*int_pointer = number;`

The second computer will only read from the 32bit int.
`number = *int_pointer;`

Both OS's / CPU's are 32bit architecture.
computer with PCI is Intel Based.
computer on the PCI card is power PC.

The case I am worried about is if the write only computer is changing the variable at the same time the read computer is reading it, causing invalid data for the read computer.
I'd like to know if the atomicity of reading / writing to the same position in memory is preserved over multiple computers.

If so, would the following prevent the race condition:

```
number = *int_pointer;
while(*int_pointer != number) {
    number = *int_pointer;
}
```

I can guarantee that writes will occur every 16ms*, and reads will occur randomly.

*times will drift since both computers have different timers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C and everything to do with the architecture itself (and a "32-bit" description of the architecture isn't really enough to decide).

Comment: What/who is the memory controller on this PCI bus?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The memory controller is the PCI Card on which the second computer resides. pax, That may be true, but the language I am using is C.

Comment: Unless you are writing a firmware on both these systems, you can avoid such ineffective methods and use features provided by OS like semaphores/mutexes/spinlocks etc....

Comment: I guess it will be an OS running in your system. So, you will have to look at your OS how it handles physical distint processor to answer your question. But, anyway, NUMA architecture is a solid concept and I believe, what your describe here can be categorized as a NUMA.

Comment: @BarathBushan Both computers run different OS / kernals and do not interact at all apart from the shared memory, there is no way to use such features. This architecture doe appear to be NUMA, haven't heard of that before thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

There is no race condition. The memory controller on the external PCI device will handle all memory read/write operations. Since all data carriers are at least 32bits wide there will not be a race condition within those 32bits.

Since the transfers use a DMA controller the interactions between memory and processors is well behaved.

See [Direct Memory Access -PCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access#PCI)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't enough information to answer this definitively.

If either of the CPUs decide to cache the memory at `*int_pointer`, this will always fail and your extra code will not fix any race condition.

Assuming both CPUs know that memory at `*int_pointer` is uncacheable, **AND** that location `*int_pointer` is aligned on a 4-byte/32-bit boundary **AND** the CPU on the PCI card has a 32 bit memory interface, **AND** the pointer is declared as a pointer to `volatile` **AND** both your C compilers implement volatile correctly, THEN it is likely that the updates will be atomic.

If any of the above conditions are not met, the result will be unpredictable and your "race detection" code is not likely to work.

**Edited to explain why `volatile` is needed**:

Here is your race condition code compiled to MIPS assembler with `-O4` and no `volatile` qualifier. (I used MIPS because the generated code is easier to read than x86 code):

```
int nonvol(int *ip) {
  int number = *ip;
  while (*ip != number) {
    number = *ip;
  }
  return number;
}
```

Disassembly output:

```
        00000000 <nonvol>:
   0:   8c820000        lw      v0,0(a0)
   4:   03e00008        jr      ra
```

The compiler has optimized the `while` loop away since it knows that `*ip` cannot change.

Here's what happens with `volatile` and the same compiler options:

```
int vol(volatile int *ip) {
  int number = *ip;
  while (*ip != number) {
    number = *ip;
  }
  return number;
}
```

Disassembly output:

```
        00000008 <vol>:
   8:   8c820000        lw      v0,0(a0)
   c:   8c830000        lw      v1,0(a0)
  10:   1443fffd        bne     v0,v1,8 <vol>
  14:   00000000        nop
  18:   03e00008        jr      ra
```

Now the `while` loop is not optimized away because using `volatile` has told the compiler that `*ip` can change at any time.

Comment: The int is aligned to a 4byte boundary, the CPU on the PCI card is 32bit. The race condition code is to detect changes occurring during a read, double reading and comparing the result is a method of checking for this (if it exists). volatile will not affect this scenario and memory being pointed to is usually not cached anyway, although caching would actually prevent this scenario from occurring at all since there would be no reads on the shared memory.

Comment: volatile absolutely will affect the situation. You should fully understand something before you dismiss it.

Comment: I see what you are saying now, Sorry I misinterpreted your answer and assumed the volatile was in reference to the read / write and not the race detection code. You are correct, I'll up-vote due to the valuable information.